# What is default ORM provider in spring boot (when using spring data JPA)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I m a beginner in Spring world.
I know JPA provides specification for ORM and it is not a JPA provider itself.

Where as, Spring data JPA adds an extra layer of abstraction on the top of our JPA provider (like Hibernate). The goal of this is to significantly reduce the amount of boilerplate code required to implement data access layers for various persistence stores. So it is also not a JPA provider. But it works with the JPA provider.

But to interact with database we need a ORM tool(like hibernate). And so far I haven't used hibernate or something similar in any of my spring application explicitly. And still able to perform CRUD operation on database. How?

Is there any default ORM tool working behind the scene?
What am I missing here?

Comment: Hibernate is the default in spring-boot.

Comment: So Hibernate is full fledged implementation for default ORM? I mean  let's say I decided to work with Hibernate explicitly. Do I need to add dependency for that? I have seen people, adding     <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>

Comment: If you are using spring boot just add `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` as dependency which will bring hibernate as dependency